# How to insert special HTML-symbols with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, special-characters, haml

When I'm saying:

```
%p= item.price + "&nbsp;dollars"
```

I'm getting

> 50&nbsp ;dollars

instead of having non-breakable space symbol.

How to insert this and another special symbols using HAML ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

How about

```
%p= item.price + "&nbsp;dollars".html_safe
```

Comment: also useful to insert non-breaking space in link_to, for example = link_to "Some&nbsp;Link".html_safe, "/someurl"

Comment: I found that this strategy doesn't actually work.  I believe what's happening is that the first string (item.price) is not html safe.  When you do the addition, you end up with a string that is not marked html_safe and you end up with the &nbsp showing up in the view.  I like the answer below (where you interpolate and then html_safe).  The other option is render on two lines - item.price on one (without html safe) and the &nbsp;dollars on the next line.

Comment: I see your point. I guess something has changed during the 20 months since I wrote this answer. I then much prefer the two line approach instead of marking the item.price as html_safe...

Comment: sweet! this helped me too.

Comment: although all you really need to do in haml is either break out of ruby (no equal sign) and use string interpolation, %p #{item.price} dollars, or create a newline with the &nbsp; dollars. This is most likely a recent haml update since this was posted in '11

Answer (score 15):

Use `!=` instead of `=`

See "Unescaping HTML" in the haml reference: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html

Answer (score 14):

The interpolation option:

```
%p= "#{item.price}&nbsp;dollars".html_safe
```

Comment: While I didn't downvote your answer I think it does have potential problem as it marks item.price as html safe which may cause a XSS issues... Given the context in this question we cannot tell for sure :-)

Comment: Quite so, but the answer that was upvoted twice uses the same html_safe option, moreover, that's about the only way you're going to get HAML to output an inline special character like that.

Comment: But you're answer is marking contents of `item.price` as html_safe, which is where the potential problem arises. The other answer marks a string constant as html_safe which is a better solution.

Comment: For certain you may be right. Like HakonB mentioned earlier, given the context of the question, we can't tell for sure what, if any, issues might arise by interpolating the `item_price` - it's just another possible answer to the question.

Answer (score 14):

I tried using `html_safe` in different ways, but none worked. Using `\xa0` as suggested by ngn didn't work, either, but it got me to try the Unicode escape of the non-breaking space, which did work:

```
"FOO\u00a0BAR"
```

and `.html_safe` isn't even needed (unless something else in the string needs that, of course).

*The Ruby Programming Language*, first edition, says: "In Ruby 1.9, double-quoted strings can include arbitrary Unicode escape characters with `\u` escapes.  In its simplest form, `\u` is followed by exactly four hexadecimal digits ..."

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for a slightly different question but I found this question searching for it...
If you have a submit tag `%input{ :type => "submit", :value => "&nbsp;dollars", :name => "very_contrived" }` even if you throw an `html_safe` on the `:value` it will not evaluate the html.
The solution is to use the rails helper... duh

```
= submit_tag "&nbsp;dollars".html_safe
```

this is pretty obvious but it tripped me up.  Legacy code + rails upgrade = this kind of stuff :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\xa0` in the string instead of `&nbsp;`.  0xa0 is the ASCII code of the non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the character itself with the escaped HTML method with most symbols other than the whitespace characters. That way i don't have to remember all the html codes. As for the whitespace characters i prefer to use CSS, this is a much cleaner way.

```
%p&= "#{item.price} $%&#*@"
```